# element.getBoundingClientRect constantly returning the initial value

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a div with text that follows the cursor (setting its `transform:translate` in the `mousemove` event).

One more thing it does, is setting the maxWidth accordingly if the popup would go past the viewport's right border - the text div gets thinner, but higher.

While the above works well, for whatev reason `div.getBoundingClientRect` refuses to report the text div's height after the max-width has been applied - it constantly returns the initial value. This problem occurs only within the script, though. Should I query it from the console, the proper (updated) height is returned. Why is that so?

```js
const div = document.querySelector("#div");
const p = document.querySelector("#p");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  div.style.maxWidth = "400px";
  div.style.transform = `translate(${e.pageX}px, ${e.pageY}px)`;

  const bRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
  p.innerHTML = bRect.height;

  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < bRect.right) {
    div.style.maxWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth - e.pageX + "px";
  }

  ;
});
```

```css
#div {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  word-break: break-all;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
<div id="div">
  Here is some text.Here is some text.Here is some text.Here is some text.Here is some text.Here is some text.
</div>
```

Please simply move your cursor towards the right border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are changing the div's max width after the `BoundingClientRect` is already calculated. So it first outputs the initial value and only then changes the max width and hence the height.

```
const bRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
p.innerHTML = bRect.height;

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < bRect.right) {
    div.style.maxWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth - e.pageX + "px";
}
```

If you want to print the height *after* the div was resized, you have to call `getBoundingClientRect` again:

```js
const div = document.querySelector("#div");
const p = document.querySelector("#p");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  div.style.maxWidth = "400px";
  div.style.transform = `translate(${e.pageX}px, ${e.pageY}px)`;
  
  const bRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < bRect.right) {
    div.style.maxWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth - e.pageX + "px";
  }
  
  p.innerHTML = div.getBoundingClientRect().height;

});
```

```css
#div {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;

  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;

  pointer-events: none;
  word-break: break-all;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
<div id="div">
  Here is some text.Here is some text.Here is some text.Here is some text.Here
  is some text.Here is some text.
</div>
```